# Using github issues for code reviews

Tags: git, github

In my organization, we moved from svn to Enterprise github for source code repository. We want to use a tool for managing code reviews but were thinking to use Github issues for that rather than adding one more tool in our CI-CD stack.

Our repository contains a development branch where all developers commit and push their code. Build and deployment also happens via the development branch.

One suggestion which many have given us is to use a staging branch where developers check-in their code, have code reviews on that branch and then perform pull requests to the development branch. We do not like that approach because it will unnecessary create additional step of pull requests. If we give  access to limited developers to perform pull requests, additional bottleneck would be created on them. And if everyone has access to perform pull requests, developers would bypass the review process and directly get pull requests done.

All of this being said, some of us are thinking to use "Github Issues" for all code review tasks. On every push to development branch, developers could create an issue with label=CodeReview. Is this a good idea?

Or should we go for solutions like Crucible/Fisheye, etc

Comment: With GitHub Enterprise, code reviews are built into the workflow.. Details here: https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/

Comment: Have added some snippets from this link as answer, may be this will help you.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/14480087/6309

Answer (score 3):

You can open a Pull Request at any point during the development process: when you have little or no code but want to share some screenshots or general ideas, when you're stuck and need help or advice, or when you're ready for someone to review your work. By using GitHub's @mention system in your Pull Request message, you can ask for feedback from specific people or teams, whether they're down the hall or ten time zones away.

Pull Requests are useful for contributing to open source projects and for managing changes to shared repositories. If you're using a Fork & Pull Model, Pull Requests provide a way to notify project maintainers about the changes you'd like them to consider. If you're using a Shared Repository Model, Pull Requests help start code review and conversation about proposed changes before they're merged into the master branch.

Discuss and review your code

Once a Pull Request has been opened, the person or team reviewing your changes may have questions or comments. Perhaps the coding style doesn't match project guidelines, the change is missing unit tests, or maybe everything looks great and props are in order. Pull Requests are designed to encourage and capture this type of conversation.

You can also continue to push to your branch in light of discussion and feedback about your commits. If someone comments that you forgot to do something or if there is a bug in the code, you can fix it in your branch and push up the change. GitHub will show your new commits and any additional feedback you may receive in the unified Pull Request view.

Merge and deploy

Once your Pull Request has been reviewed and the branch passes your tests, it's time to merge your code to the master branch for deployment. If you want to test things before merging in the repository on GitHub, you can perform the merge locally first. This is also handy if you don't have push access to the repository.

Once merged, Pull Requests preserve a record of the historical changes to your code. Because they're searchable, they let anyone go back in time to understand why and how a decision was made.

Note:
By incorporating certain keywords into the text of your Pull Request, you can associate issues with code. When your Pull Request is merged, the related issues are also closed. For example, entering the phrase Closes #32would close issue number 32 in the repository.

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to try embracing the GitHub mindset versus trying to hold on to the SVN workflow that is more familiar.  GitHub prescribes [GitHub Flow](https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/) which is branch-based. This may be a wild concept for the moment - but it will yield dividends to use the tool in the way it was designed.

> And if everyone has access to perform pull requests, developers would bypass the review process and directly get pull requests done.

While everyone can and should work off of individual branches and create pull requests, you can enforce reviews.  You have a multitude of options like:

- Use [protected branches and a required status checks](https://github.com/blog/2051-protected-branches-and-required-status-checks) to ensure no code can be merged until all your criteria is met.
- Use [branch permissions](https://help.github.com/articles/about-branch-restrictions/) to ensure only certain users can push to a protected branch.
- Repository administrators can [require pull request reviews](https://help.github.com/articles/about-pull-request-reviews/#required-reviews) receive at least one approved review from someone with write or admin permissions before they're merged into a branch.

In addition to Issues, you may want to explore [GitHub Projects](https://help.github.com/articles/about-projects/), a kanban-style board you can use to organize issues, pull requests, and notes.